# Median entropy to observe evolution of system?

Tags: entropy, ds.dynamical-systems, it.information-theory

Hello,

I am studying a dynamical system that takes as an initial condition a list. I want to analyze the evolution of Shannon's entropy in this system. I know the maximum entropy (50) and the minimum (0). Pure random conditions have almost maximum entropy, and so it is hard to analyze changes in it unless it decreases. I set up the list to have an initial value of 25 (average between maximum and minimum), so there is an equal amount to expand in either direction. Is this statistically sound?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get interest for this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can't imagine that this question has an answer absent the actual system. If the system is ergodic, then the "entropy" (of the list) will quickly rise to near 50 and remain there. If it isn't ergodic, then it will do something else that depends on the particular system.